# High DPI messes up text and icons; did not happen before reformat

Tags: windows-7, dpi, high-dpi

I have two 2560x1440 monitors running off an ATI Radeon 6970 on Windows 7.

Before reformatting, I had adjusted the DPI to 120 via Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display > "Medium - 125%". I am not entirely sure, but I think I had checked "Use Windows XP style DPI scaling" (which is the default for DPI less than 144 I believe). My apps looked fine; the text size was larger, but it never really caused any problems.

However, upon reformatting, I tried to do the same thing and have ended up with messed up text and icons in my apps. Examples:

[image: Outlook icons are resized improperly]

In Outlook, the icons are resized in crazy ways and look much worse, and the text---*except for the actual message list*---is oversized.

[image: muTorrent text overlaps]

In muTorrent, the text is too large to fit in its bounding boxes, and gets clipped.

**I have tried right-clicking on the program and choosing Properties > Compatibility > Disable display scaling on high DPI settings; this does *nothing*.**

Also of note: in Windows Explorer, things look fine; the text is not comically oversized and the icons are not scaled up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of *course* I solve this minutes after posting it, despite a couple days of banging my head against the wall X_x.

If I switch to Windows Classic theme under Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Personalization, then back to Windows 7 (Aero) theme, the fonts get resized back to reasonable and the icons stop getting scaled weirdly.

So, somehow my font size and/or DPI scaling got tied to my theme. I believe this occured because I experimented with 144 DPI (150%) for a few minutes, during which time I might have mucked around with theme settings, perhaps switching from Basic (the default) to Aero.

Comment: You should mark your question as answered

Comment: @Tog That only works in two days