# Disable display scaling on high DPI makes text too big

Tags: windows-7, display, high-dpi

I have manually checked the option "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" for most applications that used to look blurry. This has helped in most cases but in others it has messed up with the text. Do I have to chose between blurry or messed up text? Here is an example of how the text is too big for a text field on an application (Spotify).

[image: blurry vs messed up text on Spotify]

Update: I found the same problem posted before [here](https://superuser.com/questions/285070/high-dpi-messes-up-text-and-icons-did-not-happen-before-reformat/285073#285073) but tried doing exactly what that other person did and it did not fix my problem. I also see the exact same ridiculously oversized icons on Outlook and other display weirdness.

Comment: Did you do the top 3 things (you said you did 1) . reset the theme , as that refreshes at least. Change the resolution to update the registry . Change the DPI again if needed. Reboot the computer, which would lock it in and reset everything.   The idea being to insure that these changes are re-made and read again in the registry, in the case that a single registry item is reading wrong, due to some Other change made. To get the computer to re-write these registry tags, you switch it fully one way, then switch it back again.